# Finding the smallest string that contains a given set of substrings

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

The algorithm I am looking for has the following requirements: Input is a set of strings. You are looking for a string containing all input strings. The resulting string should be as short as possible. At least shorter than just concatenating all input strings if possible.

Examples:

```
Input: a ab bc
Output: abc

Input: abcd bcde ef
Output: abcdef
```

Is there a name for this problem with which it is better to search for solutions?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-superstring-problem/

Comment: @xskxzr Looks like an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is called *shortest superstring problem*. John Gallant, David Maier and James Astorer proved it is NP-hard in 1979<sup>1</sup>.

Given two strings $A$ and $B$, let $|A|$ denote the length of $A$, and let $S(A,B)$ denote the shortest superstring of $A$ and $B$ where $A$ occurs before $B$. It is easy to reduce this problem to [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), where nodes represent strings, and the distance from string $A$ to $B$ is $|S(A,B)|-|A|-|B|$. So you can use known algorithms for travelling salesman problem to solve this problem.

There are several polynomial approximation algorithms. The best known approximation factor is $2\frac{11}{23}$, and the corresponding algorithm is proposed by Marcin Mucha in 2013<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Gallant, J., Maier, D., & Astorer, J. (1980). On finding minimal length superstrings. *Journal of Computer and System Sciences*, *20*(1), 50-58.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>Mucha, M. (2013, January). Lyndon words and short superstrings. In *Proceedings of the twenty-fourth annual ACM-SIAM symposium on Discrete algorithms* (pp. 958-972). Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.</sub>

Comment: If A is "abc" and B is "cde" S(A,B) is "abcde". Calculating the distance from A to B results in -1. I thought TSP doesn't handle negative distances? What have I missed?

Comment: @Vel TSP can surely handle negative distances. At least you can add a big enough constant to all distances, and the result does not change.